# Use sed to replace matched value from associative bash array

Tags: regex, bash, replace, sed, associative-array

I'm using `sed` to reformat an input string, a portion of which I want replaced with a different string.

The input string is a date in the format of:

```
%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N%:z
Example:
2016-01-20T08:15:32.398242-05:00
```

My goal is to replace the *month*, `01` in the example above, with a string representation such as `Jan`.

I've defined the following array to use:

```
declare -A MONTHS=([01]="Jan" [02]="Feb" [03]="Mar" [04]="Apr" [05]="May" [06]="Jun" [07]="Jul" [08]="Aug" [09]="Sep" [10]="Oct" [11]="Nov" [12]="Dec")
```

I can't seem to get `sed` to use a matched group's value as the index to the `MONTHS` array.

What I've tried:

```
# straightforward sed approach
sed 's/^[0-9]\{4\}-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-.*/${MONTHS[\1]}/g'
# result: ${MONTHS[01]}

# break out of the single quotes
sed 's/^[0-9]\{4\}-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-.*/'"${MONTHS[\1]}"'/g'
# result: 

# use double quotes
sed "s/^[0-9]\{4\}-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-.*/${MONTHS[\1]}/g"
# result: 

# use double quotes *and* a hardcoded example
sed "s/^[0-9]\{4\}-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-.*/${MONTHS[\1]}, ${MONTHS[01]}/g"
# result: , Jan
```

Is it possible to use a matched-group value from `sed` as an array index in the replacement?

*Note:* I'm purposefully avoiding the `date` function because the application of this can go beyond actual dates; but, I'm definitely open to alternative approaches such as `awk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest this `awk` as an alternative:

```
s='2016-01-20T08:15:32.398242-05:00'

awk -v ms='Jan:Feb:Mar:Apr:May:Jun:Jul:Aug:Sep:Oct:Nov:Dec' 'BEGIN{
   split(ms, mths, ":"); FS=OFS="-"} {$2=mths[$2+0]} 1' <<< "$s"
```

**Output:**

```
2016-Jan-20T08:15:32.398242-05:00
```

Comment: Oh awesome, this works great! I really like that it lets me inline the replacement values too, and everything else is easy to modify to my needs. Thank you =]

Answer (score 1):

First, you can convert your associative array to a string containing the months names in order

```
monstr=$(for k in "${!MONTHS[@]}"; do echo $k; done | sort | while read mon; do echo ${MONTHS[$mon]}; done)
```

then, use `awk` to do the heavy lifting

```
awk -F- -v monstr="$monstr" 'BEGIN { split(monstr, mon, " "); } { printf("%s-%s-", $1, mon[$2+0]); for (i=3; i < NF; i++) { printf("%s-", $i); } printf("%s\n", $NF);}'
```

That is, store the string containing the months in a varaible that you split at the beginning, then replace the second field and print all.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! The multiple `printf()` statements made it a little confusing to modify at first, but I've got the hang of it now and it works exactly how I need =]

Answer (score 1):

First generate `sed` script from your array, then execute it.

Disclaimer: not sure that I correctly used bash array in the following code. Also not sure about quotes and escaping.

```
for k in $(seq -w 1 12) ; do
    echo 's/^[0-9]\{4\}-'"$k-.*/${MONTHS[$k]}/;"
done | sed -f - your_file
```

Alternatively just use `bash`:

```
IFS=- read year mon rest <<<"$string"
string="$year ${MONTHS[$mon]} $rest"
```

Answer (score 0):

If it must be sed... Here is a "brute force" answer using the *t* command:

```
#! /bin/sed -f
s/-01-/-Jan-/; tx
s/-02-/-Feb-/; tx
s/-03-/-Mar-/; tx
s/-04-/-Apr-/; tx
s/-05-/-May-/; tx
s/-06-/-Jun-/; tx
s/-07-/-Jul-/; tx
s/-08-/-Aug-/; tx
s/-09-/-Sep-/; tx
s/-10-/-Oct-/; tx
s/-11-/-Nov-/; tx
s/-12-/-Dec-/; tx
:x
```